# Random ID generator and check if it allready registered

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to create a random ID generator, my problem is I don't know how to check if it already exists. I have a `std::vector` which I use to store the IDs (`Client` is my class):

```
vector <Client> registeredIDs;
```

The function for the ID generator is this:

```
string Client::GenerateID() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    string digits[10] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" ,"6", "7", "8", "9" };
    string newID = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        newID = newID + digits[rand() % 3];
    if (CheckID(newID)) {
        newID = GenerateID();
    }
    else return newID;
}
```

I `push_back()` the returned ID outside of this function, `(i < 2)` so it generates a small ID to see if it works.

My function to check if the ID exists is this:

```
bool Client::CheckID(string _id) {
    int cnt1 = 0;
    for (cnt1; cnt1 < registeredIDs.size(); cnt1++) {
        if (_id == registeredIDs[cnt1]) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting errors when it finds the same ID, and it open the "xmemory" window at:

```
// STRUCT _Default_allocate_traits
struct _Default_allocate_traits {
    __declspec(allocator) static void* _Allocate(const size_t _Bytes) {
        return ::operator new(_Bytes);
    }
```

Can someone tell me what's causing the problem?

Comment: Use `std::set`, as it only allows one instance of an object.

Comment: What's the point of a 10 element array when you only use the first three elements?

Comment: Wanted to generate fast the same ID, its only purpose it to test if it is generating a new id.

Comment: Could you explain why you need the number to be random, instead of sequential or time-based (which are both a lot easier to avoid duplicates)?

Comment: Honestly i thought random would be the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CheckID()` function is fine, though because it returns a `bool`, you should be returning `true`/`false` rather than `1`/`0`.

But, your `GenerateID()` function has several issues:

- You are calling `srand()` to re-seed the RNG each time `GenerateID()` is called.  That means every time `GenerateID()` is called within a 1-second period (the resolution of `time()`), it will generate *the same* IDs over and over. Seeding the RNG should be done **only 1 time**, preferably at program startup.
- Your `digits[]` array has 10 strings in it, but you are using `rand() % 3`, so you are only using the first 3 strings `"0"`, `"1"`, and `"2"`.  Since you are generating only 2 random digits per ID, *at most* you can have up to 3<sup>2</sup>=9 unique IDs in your `vector`. Once the vector reaches that limit, your generator will get stuck in an endless loop where `CheckID()` always return `true`.  If you use `rand() % 10` instead, you can use all 10 strings, which will give you up to 10<sup>2</sup>=100 unique IDs.  Still not a lot, but more than you had before.  You should increase the number of digits per ID to allow for even more uniqueness.

  - That being said, you really should be using a newer [C++-based RNG](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), such as [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), instead of using a C-based RNG like `rand()`.
  - you don't really need the `digits[]` array at all.
- You are calling `GenerateID()` recursively, which has the potential to cause a stack overflow if you get stuck in an endless loop.  Use an iterative loop instead.

Try this instead:

```cpp
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
std::vector <Client> registeredIDs;

bool Client::CheckID(const string &_id) {
    for (size_t cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < registeredIDs.size(); ++cnt1) {
        if (_id == registeredIDs[cnt1]) return true;
    }
    return false;

    /* alternatively:

    return std::find(registeredIDs.begin(), registeredIDs.end(), _id) != registeredIDs.end();

    */
}

string Client::GenerateID() {
    static const int maxDigits = 2; // or whatever you want...
    string newID;
    int numAttempts = 10; // or whatever you want...
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxDigits; ++i) {
            newID += ('0' + (rand() % 10));
        }
        if (!CheckID(newID)) return newID;
        newID = "";
    }
    while (--numAttempts > 0);
    throw std::runtime_error("Cant find a unique ID!");

    /* alternatively:

    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(0, 9);
    string newID;
    int numAttempts = 10; // or whatever you want...
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxDigits; ++i) {
            newID += ('0' + distrib(gen));
        }
        if (!CheckID(newID)) return newID;
        newID = "";
    }
    while (--numAttempts > 0);
    throw std::runtime_error("Too many unique IDs in the vector!");
    
    */
}

{
    ...
    string id = GenerateID();
    registeredIDs.push_back(id);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, as for the rand % 3 i was using it to get the same ID.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is arising because you are seeding the random number generator every time you call `Client::GenerateID`.  Then, when `CheckID` finds a match, you recurse into `GenerateID` which generates the same ID as before, so you recurse again and so on, ad infinitum.  You therefore eventually (most likely) overflow the stack.

You'd get away with it if your machine had a slow CPU, but modern machines can do an awful lot of processing in 1 second, and that's the resolution of `time()`.  So, the first port of call is to only call `srand` once.

Of course, you don't need to recurse.  A simple loop is much better.  There are also [better random number generators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) than `rand` out there and `rand() % 3` should surely be `rand() % 10`.

Comment: i had it as rand() % 3 to generate fast the same ID

Comment: OK, understood.  Ignore the last part of my answer then.

Comment: I agree that this would make much more sense as a "while" loop, e.g., "while generated ID is not unique, generate a new ID." This would be easy to implement to repeatedly call rand() WITHOUT reseeding so it would actually generate new IDs. Note that you don't currently have any way to deal with running out of IDs in the ID space, by which I mean, if every possible ID has been taken you have no way to detect that. And I would actually recommend just using a hash function anyway.